# Python quit unexpectedly while running Django

Tags: python, django, crash, interpreter, osx-lion

I'm running Python 2.7.1 on 64-bit Mac OSX Lion. Python keeps crashing while I'm running my local Django 1.3 development server. The error log is below.

This is starting to get annoying. Any ideas?

> Process:         Python [22917] Path:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>   Identifier:      Python Version:         ??? (???) Code Type:
>   X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:  Python [22635]
>
> Date/Time:       2011-10-12 15:01:21.968 -0500 OS Version:      Mac OS
>   X 10.7.1 (11B26) Report Version:  9
>
> Interval Since Last Report:          293584 sec Crashes Since Last
>   Report:           6 Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   5 Anonymous
>   UUID:                      AF6F3F62-2520-45F9-AD9C-B5D08053AE23
>
> Crashed Thread:  1
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000058
>
> VM Regions Near 0x58:
>   --> 
>       __TEXT                 0000000101d94000-0000000101d95000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW 
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>
> Application Specific Information: objc[22917]: garbage collection is
>   OFF
>
> Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff91c41386 close + 10 1
>   libmysqlclient.18.dylib           0x00000001028330dc vio_close + 60 2
>   libmysqlclient.18.dylib           0x00000001028329db vio_delete + 33 3
>   libmysqlclient.18.dylib           0x0000000102818069 end_server + 50 4
>   libmysqlclient.18.dylib           0x0000000102818174 mysql_close + 101 5 
>   _mysql.so                         0x00000001028006a3 _mysql_ConnectionObject_close + 65 6   _mysql.so                         0x0000000102802274 _mysql_ConnectionObject_dealloc + 39 7
>   org.python.python                 0x0000000101df1a85 0x101d9d000 + 346757
>   8   org.python.python                 0x0000000101dd1caa 0x101d9d000 +
>   216234 9   org.python.python              0x0000000101dd473a
>   PyDict_DelItem + 186 10  org.python.python
>     0x0000000101e5255c 0x101d9d000 + 742748 11  org.python.python
>     0x0000000101da4d32 PyObject_Call + 97 12  org.python.python
>     0x0000000101da4eed PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs + 178 13 
>   org.python.python                 0x0000000101df5818 0x101d9d000 + 362520
>   14  org.python.python                 0x0000000101df5946
>   PyObject_ClearWeakRefs + 246 15  org.python.python
>     0x0000000101e51b61 0x101d9d000 + 740193 16  org.python.python
>     0x0000000101dd1caa 0x101d9d000 + 216234 17  org.python.python
>     0x0000000101e3e235 PyThreadState_Clear + 129 18  org.python.python
>     0x0000000101e3e44c PyInterpreterState_Clear + 41 19 
>   org.python.python                 0x0000000101e3fb7f Py_Finalize + 344 20
>   org.python.python                 0x0000000101e3fd90 0x101d9d000 + 667024
>   21  org.python.python                 0x0000000101e3fdc7 PyErr_PrintEx +
>   41 22  org.python.python              0x0000000101e403f4
>   PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 730 23  org.python.python
>     0x0000000101e502af Py_Main + 2715 24  org.python.python
>     0x0000000101d94e88 0x101d94000 + 3720
>
> Thread 1 Crashed: 0   org.python.python
>     0x0000000101e270dc PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 22922 1   org.python.python
>     0x0000000101e27cd8 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1996 2   org.python.python
>     0x0000000101e27e6c 0x101d9d000 + 568940 3   org.python.python
>     0x0000000101e24e0a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 14008 4   org.python.python
>     0x0000000101e27cd8 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1996 5   org.python.python
>     0x0000000101e27e6c 0x101d9d000 + 568940 6   org.python.python
>     0x0000000101e24e0a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 14008 7   org.python.python
>     0x0000000101e27cd8 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1996 8   org.python.python
>     0x0000000101dc5abf 0x101d9d000 + 166591 9   org.python.python
>     0x0000000101da4d32 PyObject_Call + 97 10  org.python.python
>     0x0000000101db36e9 0x101d9d000 + 91881 11  org.python.python
>     0x0000000101da4d32 PyObject_Call + 97 12  org.python.python
>     0x0000000101e20c40 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 180 13 
>   org.python.python                 0x0000000101e5240d 0x101d9d000 + 742413
>   14  libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff8dfcb8bf _pthread_start +
>   335 15  libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff8dfceb75 thread_start
>   + 13
>
> Thread 2: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff91c40df2
>   __select + 10 1   time.so                         0x00000001021ae030 0x1021ad000 + 4144 2   org.python.python
>     0x0000000101e24d77 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13861 3   org.python.python
>     0x0000000101e27cd8 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1996 4   org.python.python
>     0x0000000101e27e6c 0x101d9d000 + 568940 5   org.python.python
>     0x0000000101e24e0a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 14008 6   org.python.python
>     0x0000000101e27df7 0x101d9d000 + 568823 7   org.python.python
>     0x0000000101e24e0a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 14008 8   org.python.python
>     0x0000000101e27cd8 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1996 9   org.python.python
>     0x0000000101dc5abf 0x101d9d000 + 166591 10  org.python.python
>     0x0000000101da4d32 PyObject_Call + 97 11  org.python.python
>     0x0000000101db36e9 0x101d9d000 + 91881 12  org.python.python
>     0x0000000101da4d32 PyObject_Call + 97 13  org.python.python
>     0x0000000101e20c40 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 180 14 
>   org.python.python                 0x0000000101e5240d 0x101d9d000 + 742413
>   15  libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff8dfcb8bf _pthread_start +
>   335 16  libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff8dfceb75 thread_start
>   + 13
>
> Thread 1 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):   rax:
>   0x00007fab51368e10  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x00007fab5146dc90 
>   rdx: 0x0000000101ecd670   rdi: 0x00007fab5146de28  rsi:
>   0x0000000000000009  rbp: 0x0000000102dae630  rsp: 0x0000000102dae4c0
>   r8: 0x00007fff784a50b0   r9: 0x0000000102dae458  r10:
>   0x0000000000000081  r11: 0x0000000102c23064   r12: 0x00007fab51368e10 
>   r13: 0x0000000103023f90  r14: 0x000000000000007c  r15:
>   0x00000001023c4ddb   rip: 0x0000000101e270dc  rfl: 0x0000000000010246 
>   cr2: 0x0000000000000058 Logical CPU: 2
>
> Binary Images:
>          0x101d94000 -        0x101d94fff  org.python.python (2.7.1 - 2.7.1)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>          0x101d9d000 -        0x101eb8ff7  org.python.python (2.7.1 - 2.7.1)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
>          0x1020ea000 -        0x1020edfff  strop.so (??? - ???) 
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/strop.so
>          0x1020f2000 -        0x1020f5fff  operator.so (??? - ???) <59A152D0-52ED-354C-9C2D-D7390E3EC216>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so
>          0x10213b000 -        0x10213cfff  _functools.so (??? - ???) 
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_functools.so
>          0x102140000 -        0x102141fff  _locale.so (??? - ???) 
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.so
>          0x102145000 -        0x102149fff  _struct.so (??? - ???) 
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_struct.so
>          0x10218f000 -        0x102195ff7  _socket.so (??? - ???) 
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socket.so
>          0x10219d000 -        0x1021a1fff  _ssl.so (??? - ???) <50FC05D5-0434-3054-9C09-CA8923FED0C0>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
>          0x1021a7000 -        0x1021a8fff  cStringIO.so (??? - ???) 
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cStringIO.so
>          0x1021ad000 -        0x1021aefff  time.so (??? - ???) 
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so
>          0x1021b5000 -        0x1021b8fff  _collections.so (??? - ???) <62C1B5B7-654D-397A-8840-7EBB907DBCA1>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_collections.so
>          0x1021be000 -        0x1021c4fff  itertools.so (??? - ???) <7C8350B9-8DD3-377A-A5C1-1103A6C955A6>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.so
>          0x1021cd000 -        0x1021cdfff  _bisect.so (??? - ???) 
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_bisect.so
>          0x1021d1000 -        0x1021d2fff  _heapq.so (??? - ???) 
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.so
>          0x1021d7000 -        0x1021d9ff7  binascii.so (??? - ???) <9B353DAC-B0E8-3B4B-91A1-50F6F86AA928>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.so
>          0x10221d000 -        0x10221dfff  _scproxy.so (??? - ???) 
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_scproxy.so
>          0x102221000 -        0x10222cff7  datetime.so (??? - ???) <9EC1E3BD-3BD3-3B39-AE19-448CCEEA747A>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so
>          0x102322000 -        0x102327fff  math.so (??? - ???) 
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so
>          0x1023ad000 -        0x1023aefff  _hashlib.so (??? - ???) 
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so
>          0x1023b2000 -        0x1023b3ff7  _random.so (??? - ???) <3C7A7C17-1698-32D0-BF09-F50A19F75E4B>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_random.so
>          0x102437000 -        0x102443fff  cPickle.so (??? - ???) 
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cPickle.so
>          0x102449000 -        0x10244bfff  select.so (??? - ???) 
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/select.so
>          0x1024d1000 -        0x1024d2fff  fcntl.so (??? - ???) 
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/fcntl.so
>          0x102596000 -        0x10259bfff  array.so (??? - ???) <177F1D09-ACEE-3E39-8F1E-3EE8BA8A7AC6>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/array.so
>          0x102661000 -        0x102661fff  grp.so (??? - ???) <563EC9A6-F38F-3518-9BBB-912E9F01FDA1>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/grp.so
>          0x1026a5000 -        0x1026a6fff  termios.so (??? - ???) <578DA44F-17E3-3343-982F-BB543CBB49F1>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/termios.so
>          0x10276b000 -        0x10276dfff  zlib.so (??? - ???) <81E54FCE-EEAC-3E97-BB05-1143EB6AECA6>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/zlib.so
>          0x1027b2000 -        0x1027b8fff  pyexpat.so (??? - ???) <0E02E7DD-AC97-38B5-BB3B-856249DEBFF9>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.so
>          0x1027ff000 -        0x102804fff +_mysql.so (??? - ???) <8B1F4F4C-09C5-33DC-9DA4-D611FF9E2AF4> /Users/USER/*/_mysql.so
>          0x102810000 -        0x102aa0ff7  libmysqlclient.18.dylib (18.0.0 - compatibility 18.0.0) <6A688A2F-6420-D89A-A3BD-5F9605F6C4C2>
>   /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
>          0x102e31000 -        0x102e42fff  _io.so (??? - ???) <5451CA4B-98A0-3F70-9322-DBE6B7D93CF1>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
>          0x102e51000 -        0x102e5dff7 +parser.so (??? - ???) <9384AA00-C2F8-3407-94F6-210FA55AFD70>
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/http_parser/parser.so
>          0x102f2d000 -        0x102f3efff  _ctypes.so (??? - ???) <2D2AE6AF-704A-3CBB-954B-33BA49B78254>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
>          0x102f8a000 -        0x102f8efff  _json.so (??? - ???) 
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_json.so
>       0x7fff61994000 -     0x7fff619c8ac7  dyld (195.5 - ???) <4A6E2B28-C7A2-3528-ADB7-4076B9836041> /usr/lib/dyld
>       0x7fff876a6000 -     0x7fff876d3fe7  libSystem.B.dylib (159.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <7B4D685D-939C-3ABE-8780-77A1889E0DE9>
>   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>       0x7fff88a3b000 -     0x7fff88a3cfff  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (??? - ???)
>   <3DCF577B-F126-302B-BCE2-4DB9A95B8598>
>   /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
>       0x7fff89578000 -     0x7fff89593fff  libexpat.1.dylib (7.2.0 - compatibility 7.0.0) 
>   /usr/lib/libexpat.1.dylib
>       0x7fff899ec000 -     0x7fff89a25fe7  libssl.0.9.8.dylib (0.9.8 - compatibility 0.9.8) 
>   /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
>       0x7fff8a000000 -     0x7fff8a001fff  libdnsinfo.dylib (395.6.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <718A135F-6349-354A-85D5-430B128EFD57>
>   /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
>       0x7fff8a163000 -     0x7fff8a169fff  libmacho.dylib (800.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) 
>   /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
>       0x7fff8a1cf000 -     0x7fff8a1d1fff  libquarantine.dylib (36.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <4C3BFBC7-E592-3939-B376-1C2E2D7C5389>
>   /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
>       0x7fff8a223000 -     0x7fff8a224fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (??? - ???) <8D14139B-B671-35F4-9E5A-023B4C523C38> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
>       0x7fff8a225000 -     0x7fff8a22dfff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (??? - ???) <7749128E-D0C5-3832-861C-BC9913F774FA>
>   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
>       0x7fff8a28f000 -     0x7fff8a29dfff  libdispatch.dylib (187.5.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <698F8EFB-7075-3111-94E3-891156C88172>
>   /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
>       0x7fff8ae52000 -     0x7fff8ae9dfff  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.11 - 1.11) <0B02FEC4-C36E-32CB-8004-2214B6793AE8>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
>       0x7fff8afbd000 -     0x7fff8b1bffff  libicucore.A.dylib (46.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <82DCB94B-3819-3CC3-BC16-2AACA7F64F8A>
>   /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
>       0x7fff8b4bb000 -     0x7fff8b4fdff7  libcommonCrypto.dylib (55010.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0)
>   
>   /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
>       0x7fff8c12f000 -     0x7fff8c213def  libobjc.A.dylib (228.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) 
>   /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
>       0x7fff8c32b000 -     0x7fff8c39efff  libstdc++.6.dylib (52.0.0 - compatibility 7.0.0) <6BDD43E4-A4B1-379E-9ED5-8C713653DFF2>
>   /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
>       0x7fff8c711000 -     0x7fff8c713fff  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent (2.0 - 1)
>   <80AFB5D8-5CC4-3A38-83B9-A7DF5820031A>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
>       0x7fff8c74b000 -     0x7fff8c74cfff  libunc.dylib (24.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) 
>   /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
>       0x7fff8c7b5000 -     0x7fff8c8c1fef  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (0.9.8 - compatibility 0.9.8) <3AD29F8D-E3BC-3F49-A438-2C8AAB71DC99> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
>       0x7fff8cc05000 -     0x7fff8cdd8ff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.7 - 635) <57446B22-0778-3E07-9690-96AC705D57E8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
>       0x7fff8ce15000 -     0x7fff8ce1afff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (6.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <98ECD5F6-E85C-32A5-98CD-8911230CB66A>
>   /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
>       0x7fff8d07f000 -     0x7fff8d083fff  libdyld.dylib (195.5.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) 
>   /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
>       0x7fff8d6e4000 -     0x7fff8d759ff7  libc++.1.dylib (19.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) 
>   /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
>       0x7fff8df5d000 -     0x7fff8df5eff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (53.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <8BCA214A-8992-34B2-A8B9-B74DEACA1869>
>   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
>       0x7fff8df5f000 -     0x7fff8df7cff7  libxpc.dylib (77.16.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <0A4B4775-29A9-30D6-956B-3BE1DBF98090>
>   /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
>       0x7fff8df7d000 -     0x7fff8e05afef  libsystem_c.dylib (763.11.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <1D61CA57-3C6D-30F7-89CB-CC6F0787B1DC>
>   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
>       0x7fff8e3d9000 -     0x7fff8e3deff7  libsystem_network.dylib (??? - ???) <4ABCEEF3-A3F9-3E06-9682-CE00F17138B7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
>       0x7fff8e6dd000 -     0x7fff8e6deff7  libremovefile.dylib (21.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) 
>   /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
>       0x7fff8f409000 -     0x7fff8f414ff7  libc++abi.dylib (14.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <8FF3D766-D678-36F6-84AC-423C878E6D14>
>   /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
>       0x7fff8f7f7000 -     0x7fff8f7fcfff  libcache.dylib (47.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) 
>   /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
>       0x7fff8fb23000 -     0x7fff8fb23fff  libkeymgr.dylib (23.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <61EFED6A-A407-301E-B454-CD18314F0075>
>   /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
>       0x7fff8fee2000 -     0x7fff8ff30ff7  libauto.dylib (??? - ???)  /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
>       0x7fff8ff31000 -     0x7fff8ff37ff7  libunwind.dylib (30.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <1E9C6C8C-CBE8-3F4B-A5B5-E03E3AB53231>
>   /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
>       0x7fff907bd000 -     0x7fff907c1fff  libmathCommon.A.dylib (2026.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0)
>   
>   /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
>       0x7fff91aae000 -     0x7fff91ab8ff7  liblaunch.dylib (392.18.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <39EF04F2-7F0C-3435-B785-BF283727FFBD>
>   /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
>       0x7fff91ae3000 -     0x7fff91aecfff  libnotify.dylib (80.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) 
>   /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
>       0x7fff91b74000 -     0x7fff91b7bfff  libcopyfile.dylib (85.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <172B1985-F24A-34E9-8D8B-A2403C9A0399>
>   /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
>       0x7fff91c2a000 -     0x7fff91c4afff  libsystem_kernel.dylib (1699.22.73 - compatibility 1.0.0)
>   <69F2F501-72D8-3B3B-8357-F4418B3E1348>
>   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
>       0x7fff9288c000 -     0x7fff928c8fff  libsystem_info.dylib (??? - ???) 
>   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
>       0x7fff93506000 -     0x7fff93518ff7  libz.1.dylib (1.2.5 - compatibility 1.0.0) <30CBEF15-4978-3DED-8629-7109880A19D4>
>   /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
>       0x7fff939e7000 -     0x7fff939e8fff  libffi.dylib (??? - ???)  /usr/lib/libffi.dylib
>
> External Modification Summary:   Calls made by other processes
>   targeting this process:
>       task_for_pid: 0
>       thread_create: 0
>       thread_set_state: 0   Calls made by this process:
>       task_for_pid: 0
>       thread_create: 0
>       thread_set_state: 0   Calls made by all processes on this machine:
>       task_for_pid: 206162
>       thread_create: 1
>       thread_set_state: 0
>
> VM Region Summary: ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=62.8M
>   resident=27.3M(43%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=35.5M(57%) Writable
>   regions: Total=62.7M written=16.7M(27%) resident=22.3M(35%)
>   swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=40.5M(65%)   REGION TYPE
>   VIRTUAL
>   ===========                      ======= MALLOC                             53.2M MALLOC guard page                    32K STACK GUARD                        56.0M Stack                              9232K VM_ALLOCATE                           8K
>   __DATA                             2320K
>   __LINKEDIT                         48.2M
>   __TEXT                             14.6M
>   __UNICODE                           544K shared memory                        12K
>   ===========                      ======= TOTAL                             183.8M
>
> Model: MacBookPro8,1, BootROM MBP81.0047.B0E, 2 processors, Intel Core
>   i7, 2.7 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.68f96 Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel
>   HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 512 MB Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB,
>   DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334448302D4348392020 Memory
>   Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE,
>   0x4D34373142353237334448302D4348392020 AirPort:
>   spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom
>   BCM43xx 1.0 (5.100.98.75.10) Bluetooth: Version 2.5.0f17, 2 service,
>   19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports Network Service: AirPort, AirPort,
>   en1 Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD TS128C, 121.33 GB Serial ATA Device:
>   OPTIARC DVD RW AD-5970H USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC),
>   0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 3 USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom
>   Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 5 USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host
>   Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821a, 0xfa113000 / 8 USB Device: Apple
>   Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0245, 0xfa120000 / 4
>   USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509,
>   0xfa200000 / 2 USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513,
>   0xfd100000 / 2 USB Device: My Passport 0730, 0x1058  (Western Digital
>   Technologies, Inc.), 0x0730, 0xfd120000 / 4 USB Device: IR Receiver,
>   apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its the mysql-extension that crashes, if you have XCode you can try to make sure you have the latest one compiled locally and installed.